# Conditionally assign color and label to heatmap cells based on a secondary sub-grouping not used in x, y, color mappings / plot_ly conditional text

Tags: r, ggplot2, plotly, heatmap

This is an example of how my dataset looks like:

```
sampleData <- structure(list(LEVELS = structure(c(1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 
4L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 
1L), .Label = c("A", "B", "C", "D"), class = "factor"), GROUP = structure(c(1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 5L, 
5L, 5L, 5L, 1L, 1L, 5L, 1L), .Label = c("AUD", "CTO", "KOP", 
"PIL", "POH"), class = "factor"), MEMBER = structure(c(17L, 18L, 
19L, 20L, 6L, 7L, 3L, 11L, 10L, 2L, 8L, 5L, 12L, 9L, 1L, 4L, 
14L, 15L, 13L, 16L, 17L, 17L, 13L, 19L), .Label = c("AS", "Ca", 
"Fc", "FFZ", "Fg", "Fo", "Fp", "Fv", "GH1", "Lp", "Nb", "Qc", 
"Rq1", "Rt", "Rt2", "Rtcz", "T1", "T2", "T3", "T4"), class = "factor"), 
    VALUE = c(0.001, 1, 0.3, 0.04, 0.1, 0.2, 0.06, 0.08, 0.12, 
    1, 1, 0.3, 0.99, 0.56, 0.54, 0.7, 0.09, 0.1, 0.95, 0.001, 
    0.01, 0.15, 0.005, 0.001)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-24L))
```

> ```
>    LEVELS GROUP MEMBER VALUE
> 1       A   AUD     T1 0.001
> 2       B   AUD     T2 1.000
> 3       C   AUD     T3 0.300
> 4       D   AUD     T4 0.040
> 5       A   KOP     Fo 0.100
> 6       B   KOP     Fp 0.200
> 7       C   KOP     Fc 0.060
> 8       D   KOP     Nb 0.080
> 9       A   PIL     Lp 0.120
> 10      B   PIL     Ca 1.000
> 11      C   PIL     Fv 1.000
> 12      D   PIL     Fg 0.300
> 13      A   CTO     Qc 0.990
> 14      B   CTO    GH1 0.560
> 15      C   CTO     AS 0.540
> 16      D   CTO    FFZ 0.700
> 17      A   POH     Rt 0.090
> 18      B   POH    Rt2 0.100
> 19      C   POH    Rq1 0.950
> 20      D   POH   Rtcz 0.001
> 21      B   AUD     T1 0.010
> 22      C   AUD     T1 0.150
> 23      A   POH    Rq1 0.005
> 24      A   AUD     T3 0.001
> ```

I want to show `LEVELS` on `y axis` and `GROUP` on `x`. If `VALUE < 0.05` the corresponding cell will be `red`.

But each `GROUP` has several `MEMBER`s. **Even if one `MEMBER` in a particular `GROUP:LEVELS` pair is < 0.05 the cell should be RED**. There is no need for ALL members of a `GROUP:LEVELS` pair to be smaller than 0.05 for that cell to be assigned red color. **But I want to report the name of ALL `MEMBER`s that are < 0.05 in each `GROUP:LEVELS` pair.**

This is one example of a case that satisfies this condition:

> ```
>    LEVELS GROUP MEMBER VALUE
> 1       A   AUD     T1 0.001
> 24      A   AUD     T3 0.001
> ```

Therefore, if I hover over the cell `A:AUD` I wish to see both `T1` and `T3` reported.

**To reiterate;**

- I want to make sure a certain cell is assigned red color even if there is only one `MEMBER` that has `VALUE < 0.05`.
- If there is more than one member satisfying the `VALUE < 0.05` condition, I want to report all of those `MEMBER`'s names in my plotly text.

How can I do this?

My current code is as follows which seems to be working well in showing red cells even if one MEMBER in a certain `GROUP:LEVELS` pair has `VALUE < 0.05`. But `plotly` only reports the name of one `MEMBER` even if there are more `MEMBER`s that have `VALUE < 0.05`.

```
library(plotly)
library(dplyr)

vals <- unique(scales::rescale(c(sampleData$VALUE)))
o <- order(vals, decreasing = FALSE)
cols <- scales::col_numeric("Blues", domain = NULL)(vals)
colz <- setNames(data.frame(vals[o], cols[o]), NULL)
names(colz) <- c("var","col")
colz$col <- as.character(colz$col)

colz <- dplyr::mutate(colz, col = replace(col, var < 0.05, "#ff3300"))

plotly::plot_ly(data = sampleData,
                x = ~GROUP, 
                y = ~LEVELS,
                z = ~VALUE, 
                type = "heatmap", 
                xgap = 0.5, ygap = 0.2,
                hoverinfo = 'text',
                text = ~paste('</br> Member: ', MEMBER),
                colorscale = colz
)
```

Comment: Just to clarify, what do you want the label to say when hovering over a cell that has no values < 0.05, e.g. **C:AUD**, should it return `T1, T3` even though the corresponding values are > 0.05? What about **A:POH** which has two values, one < 0.05 and one > 0.05

Comment: @StuartAllen `VALUE`s that are > 0.05 have no importance and thus I would prefer not to label them at all. The important values are just the ones that are < 0.05. Therefore, I only want to report those. So in the case of **A:POH** I wish to only report `Rq1` since this is the only MEMBER that satisfies the condition. I wonder if this would be as simple as specifying a condition in `plot_ly`'s text parameter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A solution is to create a new column in `sampleData` which will hold the labels, then in the call to `plot_ly()` refer to this new column rather than `MEMBER`. This way you can customise the labels to be whatever you like - so in this case we can aggregate multiple labels where necessary, and only display labels for cells having at least one value < 0.05.

The new code is inserted below, plus a slight change to the `plot_ly()` call. What it does is create a `labels` dataframe by filtering `sampleData` to rows having value < 0.05. It then aggregates the labels by grouping on **LEVELS:GROUP** - e.g. for **A:AUD** the label will be "T1 T3". Then these labels are merged (or rather `join`ed) back into `sampleData`, with the " Member: " text prepended, and labels set to empty string where we don't want a label displayed. Then in the `plot_ly()` call you just need to reference the `label` column.

```
library(plotly)
library(dplyr)

vals <- unique(scales::rescale(c(sampleData$VALUE)))
o <- order(vals, decreasing = FALSE)
cols <- scales::col_numeric("Blues", domain = NULL)(vals)
colz <- setNames(data.frame(vals[o], cols[o]), NULL)
names(colz) <- c("var","col")
colz$col <- as.character(colz$col)

colz <- dplyr::mutate(colz, col = replace(col, var < 0.05, "#ff3300"))

# filter data to values < 0.05
labels <- filter(sampleData, VALUE < 0.05)
# aggregate the labels for each unique combination of LEVEL:GROUP
labelsAgg <- aggregate(labels$MEMBER, list(labels$LEVELS, labels$GROUP), paste, collapse = " ")
# set names to match sampleData
labelsAgg <- setNames(labelsAgg, c("LEVELS", "GROUP", "label"))
# prepend "Member" heading, must do this here so that labels we want to be blank are truly blank
labelsAgg$label <- paste("</br> Member: ", labelsAgg$label)
# merge/join labels back with sampleData, using merge() here messed up the factors, so using left_join() is a workaround
sampleData <- left_join(sampleData, labelsAgg,  by = c("LEVELS", "GROUP"))
# replace NA with empty string, otherwise "NA" appears as the label
sampleData[is.na(sampleData$label), "label"] <- ""

# note the text parameter is simply the label now, i.e. the new column sampleData$label
plotly::plot_ly(data = sampleData,
                x = ~GROUP, 
                y = ~LEVELS,
                z = ~VALUE, 
                type = "heatmap", 
                xgap = 0.5, ygap = 0.2,
                hoverinfo = 'text',
                text = ~paste(label),
                colorscale = colz
)
```

You can easily change the format of the labels using the collapse parameter if, say, you prefer a comma separator rather than a space.

You could certainly tidy the added code a little if you like, though it seems to do the trick.

[image]